# Are these .VBS files that appeared in startup folder dangerous?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I was cleaning up my windows 10 computer as I have been having performance issues when I found these four .vbs files in my startup folder:

BIOS.vbs:

```
Set f = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
f.Run """C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\Java CDJ\Java.exe"""
```

Boot Logo.vbs:

```
Set f = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
f.Run """C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\Net Freamwork\.net.exe"""
```

CPU.vbs:

```
Set f = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
f.Run """C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\Java CDJ\Java Key.exe"""
```

Windows Security.vbs:

```
Set f = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
f.Run """C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\Java CDJ\Java32.exe"""
```

I removed them from the folder as I know this is not normal.
Does anyone know what they do? I guess they launch what are most likely viruses but I need other opinions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/). Also, [related](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512587.aspx). Whenever executables appear in a templates folder or things appear in a startup folder that neither you nor your system administrator put there, chances are in the low triple digits that your system has been compromised. Backup your data, flatten, and rebuild.

Comment: Yes this is dangerous ! 
Download and clean your computer with [Kaspersky Virus Removal Tool](https://www.kaspersky.com/downloads/thank-you/free-virus-removal-tool), after that,backup your data and change all yours passwords because i think your system has been compromised !

Comment: I also found a tunnel vpn so i removed it. Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
Virtual

Comment: *\*sigh\** Did the two of you actually *read* the article I linked?